# Update value inside json matching a criteria

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have entries (json datatype) in my database with some typos. I want to update them with a correct one

I'm using a PostgreSQL 9.4

This is what I'm trying:

```
UPDATE table
SET infos = infos || '{ "key1": { "key2": "new text with no typo" } }'
WHERE contact_id = (SELECT contact_id FROM table WHERE infos::TEXT LIKE '%criteria%');
```

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE public.timeline (
    contact_id serial NOT NULL,
    infos json NULL,
    CONSTRAINT contacts_pkey PRIMARY KEY (contact_id)
);
```

I expect to automatically update all the lines containing the typo.

Solution:

```
UPDATE table
SET infos = jsonb_set(to_jsonb(infos), '{key1,key2}', '{"key2": "new value to replace"}', false)
WHERE contact_id IN (SELECT contact_id FROM table WHERE infos->'key1'->>'key2' LIKE '%word_to_match%');
```

Comment: have you tried to use a `IN` instead of a = ? -> `contact_id IN (SELECT contact_id ...)`

Comment: Doesn't work either. "SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: column "infos" is of type json but expression is of type text"

Comment: can you put a DDL with some data, especially the infos columns please?

Comment: pls check https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rU2cq6VsrQJUBCcKU8bvoc/0

Comment: @AndyK thanks for your help, I added the DDL, the command in your last post didn't work, same error as I'm getting probably because of the datatype. I tryed JSONB_SET but it says the function was not found

Comment: did you manage to have a look at my dbfiddle ?

Comment: Yes I did, as the column is set to TEXT, in your example, the merge happens with no problem, but not on my db.

Comment: @AndyK I updated dbfiddle with the same schema as my bank, now gives the same error

Comment: Would you mind updating the fiddle, save it and put the link in the comments, please?

Comment: @AndyK https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rU2cq6VsrQJUBCcKU8bvoc/2

Comment: please have a look at the updated version https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rU2cq6VsrQJUBCcKU8bvoc/3 or this version from a friend  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=52f234d2ca2444f61a2a4f60c2296dea